# Is it possible to use Antlr's gUnit with the C++ target?

Tags: c++, parsing, testing, antlr

I found the gUnit tutorial at http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/gUnit+-+Grammar+Unit+Testing but it just seems to cover the Java target.  Can you also use it with a C++ target parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gUnit only works with Java targetted grammars.